# Java - Find out if either a GUI or a CLI is available

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

We have a Java server application which is using YAJSW in order to be run as a windows service. Sometimes the user will be prompted for specific stuff on server startup, such prompting can happen when there is a GUI (via a dialog) or a commandline (via commandline output and input). However, when running as a windows service, there is no way to ask the user for input.

Is there any way to find out if there is no GUI and no CLI available?

As far as I know, `GraphicsEnvironment#isHeadless` always returns true if a CLI is available, so it will return true when running as a Windows service as well. Therefore I won't be able to distinguish between those two modes.

What I thought I could do, is to simply pass a commandline parameter to the java server application (for example `--iswindowsservice`) which allows the programmer to distinguish between CLI and windows service mode.

Would there be any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: When in doubt, that parameter is a valid approach. Alternatively, using an ENV variable or system property would work.

Comment: Nice idea, a system property actually sounds easier. But I assume there is no built-in way to determine this status without manually passing anything, right?

Comment: If I would know that, I would have written an answer already ;-)

Comment: Good point, I am little bit slow today ^^